# PHP syntax checking?

Tags: php, syntax, text-editor

I'm using TextWrangler to edit PHP code.  I often run into the problem that the code just displays as a blank page in my development environment.  Is there a good way to further target which place I should look in my code for the problem?

Right now I'm just manually running through every line any time I run into this, but I'm guessing there is some sort of solution for this that I haven't been able to find the name for..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure your development php.ini file contains:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

or

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Even with these on, sometimes an out-of-memory error can cause a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Set php.ini `error_reporting` to E_ALL

```
display_error = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

You can do this in your code also.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

You can read more about [error reporting here.](http://is.php.net/error_reporting)

Answer (score 0):

In the development process you should always set the [error reporting](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the highest level ([`E_ALL`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-all)/[`E_STRICT`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-strict)) to get every error reported.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while (students learn PHP in some of my classes) because I tried using

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

as suggested (e.g. Ullman's PHPv6 and MySQL 5), but placing it in your code did not catch any parse errors. Instead I continued to see blank pages.

A [comment](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096) in the PHP Manual webpages has given me a clue as to why setting

```
display_errors = On
```

in php.ini is not quite the same as adding

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the top of your php script. It seems that PHP has a 2-phase operation and parses the script file completely before it starts to execute any of it. If parsing fails because of a missing ";" or ")", then the

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

gets parsed but never executed and so the parse error is not reported.
The same comment offers a way to report parse errors if you do not have the means to change the php.ini settings.